# Retrieve all subscriptions Stripe with an end date of certain day

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

Trying to pull in all subscriptions where the end date equals a certain date not including the Hours, Minutes, or Seconds

So if I have two subscriptions where the end date is on today so 3/15/2021 I would like to pull in the following subscriptions
-3/15/2021 4:27:13 PM
-3/15/2021 5:27:13 PM

```
var options = new SubscriptionListOptions
        {
            CurrentPeriodEnd = DateTime.Now,
        };

        var service = new SubscriptionService();
        StripeList<Subscription> subscriptions = service.List(options);
        foreach (Subscription sub in subscriptions)
        {
            string customerId = sub.CustomerId;
        }
```

This is what I have so far. I was thinking about doing a CurrentPeriodEnd is between today at 12:00AM and 11:59 PM but it has to be an equals inside to pass the parameter

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further looking into the Current Period End it is actually a
AnyOf<DateTime?, DateRangeOptions>

So my new line of code is

```
CurrentPeriodEnd = new DateRangeOptions() { GreaterThanOrEqual = DateTime.Today, LessThan = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)},
```

Answer (score 0):

As [the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list#list_subscriptions-current_period_end) say:

> The value can be a string with an integer Unix timestamp, or it can be a dictionary with the following options...

For this you can use that dictionary of options to provide both `gte` and `lte` to bound the day you're looking for, borrowing an [example from the library repository](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/3b2ed3af048889e19ecdaaf2edcdea275848f317/src/StripeTests/Infrastructure/FormEncoding/FormEncoderTest.cs#L191-L195):

```
var CurrentPeriodEndOptions = new DateRangeOptions
  {
    LessThanOrEqual = DateTime.Parse("2021-03-16T00:00:00.0000000Z"),
    GreaterThanOrEqual = DateTime.Parse("2021-03-15T00:00:00.0000000Z"),
  },
var options = new SubscriptionListOptions
{
  CurrentPeriodEnd = CurrentPeriodEndOptions,
};
var service = new SubscriptionService();
StripeList<Subscription> subscriptions = service.List(
  options
);
```

Any further filtering you would need to apply in code on the results returned.